# Counting a specific variable within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of data with a startDate variable - How would I go about returning the total number of objects with the variable of date and then just print the number?

```
$date = Todays date

foreach ($results->data as $row) {

    $checkDate = $row->startDate;

    if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->startDate)) == $date){

      Return total of date found
    }
}
```

Comment: `$total++;` in the if?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Can you please do an example so I can give some credit to you :).  Counts have always confused me and yet if I get a tricky situation its basic

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Incrementing a counter variable to count things is a really basic programming task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increment a counter whenever it is found:

```
$date = '2019-02-20';
$total = 0;

foreach ($results->data as $row) {   
    if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->startDate)) == $date){
        $total++;  // same as $total = $total + 1;
    }
}
echo "$date found $total times";
```